# How to associate models with User model in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models User and Event in my rails application, but user_id is always NULL in my events table

```
+----+------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | date       | time     | venue       | created_at          | user_id |
+----+------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | 0011-11-11 | 12:00:00 | ait pune    | 2015-09-18 11:16:51 |    NULL |
|  2 | 0011-11-11 | 12:00:00 | dighi hills | 2015-09-18 14:29:01 |    NULL |
|  3 | 0011-11-11 | 12:00:00 | obh         | 2015-09-18 14:32:41 |    NULL |
|  4 | 0011-11-11 | 12:00:00 | nbh         | 2015-09-18 14:46:40 |    NULL |
+----+------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Below is my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150918134819) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.string   "venue",      limit: 255
    t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 4
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

User and Event model are given below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong

Comment: Without knowing how you're actually creating the events or associating them with their user it's impossible to help.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Your model seems ok, but should provide us info about creating associations.

Comment: I submitted an edit -- For searching, it is best to copy/paste the table into the question, rather than posting a screen shot. Just like code, the table is helpful in text format.

Comment: what is your rails version?

Answer (score 0):

It should be [the has_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Usage**

```
arsen = User.create
arsen.events << Event.create

Event.create(user: arsen)
```

> A has_many association indicates a one-to-many connection with another
>   model. You'll often find this association on the "other side" of a
>   belongs_to association. This association indicates that each instance
>   of the model has zero or more instances of another model. For example,
>   in an application containing customers and orders, the customer model
>   could be declared like this:

[image]